# Vuejs setting the data is not reactive

Tags: vue.js

am completely new to Vuejs, sorry if this is a stupid question.
This is a nuxt app and am using an IntersectionObserver and depends on the element visibility am trying to change the internal state (data). but its not reactive unless i hit the refresh in vue dev tools.

so this is my approach

```
async mounted(){
    let options = {
        root: document.querySelector('#scroll-root'),
        rootMargin: '0px',
        threshold: 1.0
      }
    
    const testimonialStart:any = document.querySelector('#testimonial-start')
    let startObserver = new IntersectionObserver(((entries,observer)=>{
        entries.forEach((entry)=>{
            if(entry.isIntersecting){
              this.updateTesti(false)
            }
            else{
              this.updateTesti(true)
            }
        })
    }), options);
    startObserver.observe(testimonialStart)
  }
```

in the methods

```
updateTesti(st:boolean){
    this.testiPrev = st
    console.log(st,'state')
},
```

in the data

```
data(){
   return {
      testiPrev:false,

   }
}
```

there is no issues in the intersection observer, in the console.log am getting the boolean value as expected.
what should i need to do to get reactivity here?

**temporary solution:**
I found that if I add testiPrev like below inside **watch** am getting the reactivity.

```
watch: {
   testiPrev: function(){
   }
```

},

this made me to ask one more question, do we need to explicitly include all the properties inside watch to achieve reactivity, if any better way please let me know.

Comment: Where are you setting up the observer?  In the mounted method?

Comment: @StevenB. Yes in the mounted method

Comment: So is it hitting the `updateTesti` method at all?

Comment: its hitting updateTesti method and even am getting the console logs correctly

Comment: @StevenB. i found adding testiPrev inside watch making it reactive. I thought watch is similar to useEffect. Thanks anyways

Comment: Try to use a breakpoint inside method updateTesti and check if `this.testiPrev` is already initialized with false

Comment: What version of nuxt and vue you are using? I tried to replicate your issue but with the same code everything is working and the view is updating

Comment: And no, you don't need to use watch for every property. In the vue docs, it's recommended to use `computed` instead of `watch` when you can: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html but I think that in your scenario you don't even need to use computed/watch